# Does a language package for eclipse need to be installed?

Tags: java

i need to print some special characters that supposed to be as unicode. The code is as follows

```
   public class Greek {
        public static void main (String [] args){
                System.out.println("\u0391\t\u03B1\t" + "alpha\t" + "a\t" + "\"father\"");
            System.out.println("\u0392\t\u03B2\t" + "beta\t" + "b");
            System.out.println("\u0393\t\u03B3\t" + "gamma\t" + "g"); 
            System.out.println("\u0394\t\u03B4\t" + "delta\t" + "d");
            System.out.println("\u0395\t\u03B5\t" + "epsilon\t" + "e\t" + "\"end\"");
            System.out.println("\u0396\t\u03B6\t" + "z\u00EAta\t" + "z");
            System.out.println("\u0397\t\u03B7\t" + "\u00EAta\t" + "\u00EA\t" + "\"hey\"");
        System.out.println("\u0398\t\u03B8\t" + "th\u00EAta\t" + "th\t" + "\"thick\"");
            System.out.println("\u0399\t\u03B9\t" + "iota\t" + "i\t" + "\"it\"");
        System.out.println("\u039A\t\u03BA\t" + "kappa\t" + "k");
        System.out.println("\u039B\t\u03BB\t" + "lamda\t" + "l");
        System.out.println("\u039C\t\u03BC\t" + "mu\t" + "m");
        System.out.println("\u039D\t\u03BD\t" + "nu\t" + "n");
        System.out.println("\u039E\t\u03BE\t" + "xi\t" + "ks\t" + "\"box\"");
        System.out.println("\u039F\t\u03BF\t" + "omikron\t" + "o\t" + "\"off\"");
        System.out.println("\u03A0\t\u03C0\t" + "pi\t" + "p");
        System.out.println("\u03A1\t\u03C1\t" + "rho\t" + "r");
        System.out.println("\u03A3\t\u03C3,\u03C2\t" + "sigma\t" + "s\t" + "\"say\"");
        System.out.println("\u03A4\t\u03C4\t" + "tau\t" + "t");
        System.out.println("\u03A5\t\u03C5\t" + "upsilon\t" + "u\t" + "\"put\"");
        System.out.println("\u03A6\t\u03C6\t" + "phi\t" + "f");
        System.out.println("\u03A7\t\u03C7\t" + "chi\t" + "ch\t" + "\"Bach\"");
        System.out.println("\u03A8\t\u03C8\t" + "psi\t" + "ps");
        System.out.println("\u03A9\t\u03C9\t" + "omega\t" + "\u00F4\t" + "\"grow\"");

    }

}
```

my question is that do i need to install language package to computers since i am not sure eclipse will include language package when i download and install it?

thanks

Comment: Remember that `println()` is a fickle way to test this because Java might not use the same encoding as your operating system console (common on OS X), or the characters might be unsupported (as can happen when using Windows which sets an OEM charset in `cmd.exe`).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just try? But as far as I know, you don't need to. It will print them correctly (as it supports utf-8 encoding)

Comment: I did. It run on my computer. But i am not sure whether or not it will run on other computer as mac,...?

Comment: @user1993617 It will run. Whether it will do what you want depends on what you want to ultimately accomplish. Writing text into a text file or into a GUI will always work, printing it to the console Depends (tm). It has nothing to do with any sort of language package but on the environment of the program and how it's configured.